# Is $\mathcal l^2$ compact-homogeneous?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider the space $\mathcal{l}^2$ as a metric space, i.e. the space of real valued sequences with finite $l^2$-norm $\Vert (a_n)_n \Vert:= \left( \sum_{n=1} ^\infty a_{n} ^2 \right)^{1/2}$ and metric induced by this norm. Let $K$ and $K'$ be compact subspaces of $\mathcal{l}^2$. If $K$ is isometric to $K'$, is there a global isometry $T\colon \mathcal{l}^2 \to \mathcal{l}^2$ such that
\begin{align*}
  T(K)=K' \ \   ?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Let $e_i$ denote the sequence which is $1$ at $i$ and $0$ else. Then the sets $K_1=\{\frac{1}{n-1}e_n :  n\geq 2\}\cup \{0\}$ and $K_2=\{\frac{1}{n}e_n : n\geq 1\}\cup \{0\} $ are compact and isometric. However, the only isometry $S:K_1\to K_2$ is given by the left shift operator. This map cannot be extended to the point $e_1$.